# Why am I still getting the error "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: contacts"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, nested-forms

When I try to make new Girl record with leaving mail field blank, I get this error.
The mail field is nested.

When it's not input, I just want it to make only Girl record without creating contact record.
And when it's filled with something, I want it to make both Girl and Contact record.
When it's update, I want it do the same thing.
How can I do that??? What's wrong with my code?

My View

```
<%= form_for(@girl) do |f| %>
  <% if @girl.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@girl.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this girl from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @girl.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name_en %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name_en %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name_ja %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name_ja %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :gender_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :gender_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :job_type_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :job_type_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :age %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :age %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :contacts do |contact| %>
    <%= f.label :mail %><br />
    <%= contact.text_field :mail %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :photo %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :tag_list, 'tag' %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
    </div> 

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My controller

```
  def new

    @girl = Girl.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @girl }
    end
  end


  def create

    @girl = Girl.new(params[:girl])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @girl.save
        format.html { redirect_to @girl, notice: 'Girl was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @girl, status: :created, location: @girl }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @girl.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update

    @girl = Girl.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @girl.update_attributes(params[:girl])
        format.html { redirect_to @girl, notice: 'Girl was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @girl.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Girl model

```
class Girl < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_one :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
  attr_accessible :id, :name_en, :name_ja, :gender_id, :job_type_id, :age, :contact_attributes, :photo, :tag_list

  searchable do 
    text :name_en, :name_ja
    text :contact do 
      contact.mail 
    end 
  end

    has_attached_file :photo,
     :styles => {
       :thumb=> "100x100>",
       :small  => "400x400>" } 

  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  acts_as_commentable


end
```

Contact model

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :girl, :class_name => "Girl"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :girl
  attr_accessible :mail

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue that can occur with the newest version of rails since they patched it.  You can change it in the config.  See http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/30/ann-rails-3-2-3-has-been-released/ for details.

It looks like you are using the plural when the singular should be used in your form.

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :contacts do |contact| %>
    <%= f.label :mail %><br />
    <%= contact.text_field :mail %>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

Should be:

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :contact do |contact| %>
    <%= f.label :mail %><br />
    <%= contact.text_field :mail %>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

You will need to add the following to the controller for the new action:

```
@girl.build_contact
```

Comment: Thanks!! I just added @ girl.contacts = params[:girl][:contacts]  in front of if @ girl.save in create method. But it still says the same error. What else am I missing??

Comment: You need to remove the contacts section from the params.  `params[:girl].delete(:contacts)` before your `update_attributes` call.

Comment: If I make it singular as contact, message input box is gone. It disappeared

Comment: if you could, could you please copy or edit my codes and revise??

Comment: thanks. but now mail input is gone.. It's disappeared. Is it because it's null?? and the problem happens when I try to create new record.

Comment: Where does attr_accessible :mail, :contacts  should go to? Girl model? or Contact Model? Sorry for noob questions.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, try my edit first, if that doesn't work. the `attr_accessible :contacts` should be added to the Girl model **not** the Contact model.

Comment: what about 'contact_attributes' in Girl model??? Should I delete it instead of putting 'contacts'? and in view, If I change it to singular 'contact' mail field is diappeared... so I changed it back to 'contacts' and it came back. But it still says unknown attribute: contacts when I try to create record... I'm totally lost.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13863/discussion-between-gazler-and-mkk)